# Echo + Confirm doesnt work,

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello I got a looped echo that I use to get some mysql database info to it and it works fine , I've done the update button and it works but I got some problems in the echo'';       in the delete href , I try `onclick ="return confirm ('Are you sure?')"`but it doesn't work because the echo uses ' ' so i I make (' are you sure ' ) it wont work and will give errors cuz it disturbs the echo, so the only way is make it ("are you sure") but it doesn't work, I need anyone to help me solve it.

p.s: the code works in another template but not in the echo.

```
echo'
                          <tr>
                             <td>'.$row["news_id"].'</td>
                             <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row["title"].'</td>
                             <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; '.htmlentities($content).' </td>
                             <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row["disable"].'</td>
                             <td>'.$row["created_date"].'</td>
                             <td>
                              <div class="btn-group">
                                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon_plus_alt2"></i></a>
                                  <a class="btn btn-success" href="'.site_name.'admin/pages/updatenews.php?nid='.$row["news_id"].'"><i class="icon_check_alt2"></i></a>
                                  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="'.site_name.'admin/pages/deletenews.php?nid='.$row["news_id"].'"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                          </tr> ';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Sentences are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backslash before the single quotes,
something like this should work:

```
onclick ="return confirm (\'Are you sure?\')"
```